# Could someone fix this error on pine script on Gold trading strategy bot

Tags: compiler-errors, pine-script

This pine script shows errors and couldnot fixed.. someone solve this above error in this pine script?

10:18:45 AM Error at 5:45 Undeclared identifier 'input'

10:18:45 AM Error at 5:40 The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
10:18:45 AM Error at 6:40 The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
10:18:45 AM Error at 7:60 The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
10:18:45 AM Error at 10:7 Could not find function or function reference 'ema'

```
//@version=5
strategy("XAU/USD EMA and ATR Strategy", overlay=true)

// Define Inputs
ema_period = input(title="EMA Period", type=input.integer, defval=20)
atr_period = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=14)
stop_loss_multiplier = input(title="Stop Loss Multiplier", type=input.float, defval=2.0)

// Define Indicators
ema = ema(close, ema_period)
atr = atr(atr_period)

// Define Strategy
longCondition = crossover(close, ema)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", stop=close - atr * stop_loss_multiplier)

shortCondition = crossunder(close, ema)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop=close + atr * stop_loss_multiplier)

//  Plot Indicators
plot(ema, color=color.orange)
plot(atr, color=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

In v5, `input()` function is now [split](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#split-of-input-into-several-functions) into several functions and also functions have been moved to their own [namespace](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#renamed-functions-and-variables).

```
//@version=5
strategy("XAU/USD EMA and ATR Strategy", overlay=true)

// Define Inputs
ema_period = input.int(title="EMA Period", defval=20)
atr_period = input.int(title="ATR Period", defval=14)
stop_loss_multiplier = input.float(title="Stop Loss Multiplier", defval=2.0)

// Define Indicators
ema = ta.ema(close, ema_period)
atr = ta.atr(atr_period)

// Define Strategy
longCondition = ta.crossover(close, ema)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", stop=close - atr * stop_loss_multiplier)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(close, ema)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop=close + atr * stop_loss_multiplier)

//  Plot Indicators
plot(ema, color=color.orange)
plot(atr, color=color.blue)
```